# port redirection on solaris 11

Tags: port-forwarding, solaris-11, nat

I'm trying port forwarding on solaris 11. I have a mechine behind a server that use solaris 11. I try to access that mechine from the external port, and forwarded by solaris 11 mechine to that machine using the ip filter. I give ipnat.conf configuration like this:

```
rdr net0 0.0.0.0/0 port 1428 -> 10.1.18.178 port 22
```

but the response appeared when I tried to remote is connection time out, but if I redirect to a solaris 11 machine itself, the configuration is running well.

I've enabled IP forwarding on the system

```
root@solaris11:/etc/ipf# ndd -get /dev/ip ip_forwarding
1

root@solaris11:/etc/ipf# routeadm
              Configuration   Current              Current
                     Option   Configuration        System State
---------------------------------------------------------------
               IPv4 routing   enabled              enabled
               IPv6 routing   disabled             disabled
            IPv4 forwarding   enabled              enabled
            IPv6 forwarding   disabled             disabled

root@solaris11:/etc/ipf# ipadm show-prop
PROTO PROPERTY              PERM CURRENT      PERSISTENT   DEFAULT      POSSIBLE
ipv4  forwarding            rw   on           on           off          on,off
```

is there any configuration that I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but Oracle's Solaris 11.1 documentation has this (see below).
It may be that you explcitly have to name an Ethernet interface or interfaces not just a protocol layer.
I'll update this answer to confirm or alter the content as required when I get the time to repeat your activity.

```
# ipadm show-ifprop -p forwarding net0
IFNAME   PROPERTY     PROTO   PERM   CURRENT   PERSISTENT   DEFAULT   POSSIBLE
net0     forwarding   ipv4    rw     off       off          off       on,off
net0     forwarding   ipv6    rw     off       --           off       on,off

# ipadm set-ifprop -p forwarding=on -m ipv4 net0
# ipadm show-ifprop net0
IFNAME   PROPERTY         PROTO  PERM  CURRENT  PERSISTENT  DEFAULT   POSSIBLE
...
net0     forwarding       ipv4   rw    on       on          off       on,off
...
```